# How do you use 'site:' to search Google for just the domain without all the other subdomains appearing?

Tags: google-search

When I use the `site:` operator to search for domains, it returns all the other matched subdomains as well. However, I only want to see what's indexed for the main site. For example:

`site:google.com` returns result of `abc.google.com` as well, but I only want to see what's on `google.com`

I don't want to use `site:google.com -site:abc.google.com` since I don't want to enumerate through all the other subdomains.

Is there a way to do "exact" match with the `site:` operator?

Answer (score 6):

If the site starts with the subdomain `www` you can use just:

`site:www.google.com`

This should only show `www.google.com` (followed by a path), and not all the other `*.google.com` subdomains.

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
site:example.com -site:*.example.com
```

Just replace the domain with the one you're searching (duh)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. That's one of the reason that in the past prevented me to switch from the www hostname to the non-www root domain.

In fact, if the main site domain starts with www, you can filter with

```
site:www.example.com
```

However, there is a small trick. Rather than using the `site:` operator you can try with `inurl` operator along with a `+`.

See for example

```
site:stackoverflow.com blog
```

vs

```
blog +[inurl:http://stackoverflow.com]
```

If you have multiple words to search for you may want to quote them if they are a single word.

```
"Ruby 2" +[inurl:http://stackoverflow.com]
```

Comment: Unfortunately `inurl:` will show all the URLs containing that string, resulting in other domains and subdomains appearing. Try: `blog +[inurl:http://google.com]` or click [here](http://bit.ly/JRydOs). (I had `inurl:` in my initial edit, but removed it after testing variations of it).

Comment: This is true, there are several false positive, but while the number of false positive can be large if the domain is well known (such as google.com), in the majority other cases the query may return an acceptable result set. In any case, it is worth a a mention and a try ;)

Comment: Yes, it depends on how popular the site is, and if it's referenced a lot in the URLs of other sites. For one user with not that large a site however, the results weren't usable, so after testing a few more sites, it seemed to not be a very reliable solution, especially with the OP's example usage of `google.com`.